# django use Modelform to save data

Tags: python, ajax, django

I use AJAX to save data into a database and I have a question. The message board will send 3 variables, which are inputted by the user: name, email, and message. It didn't send the IP, but I have to save it into the database. How can I edit the `views.py` to get the IP? Please guide me.

Thank you very much

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'message','ip']
```

views.py

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']  #not work
            m = form.save()
            return HttpResponse(2)
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
```

this my ajax part: 
I didn't sent ip in here,

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'core:create_post' %}',
        data: {
                "name":name,
                "email":email,
                "message":message,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(ts){
            alert('操作失敗');
            window.location.reload();
        },
        success: function(dataArr){
            if(dataArr == 2){ 
                alert('Sudccess!');
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                alert('something wrong!');
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `ip` field from `ModelForm`. Otherwise `form.is_valid()` will return `False` because the `ip` field is not from user input.

Next you have to save the `ModelForm` with `commit=False`. This will not store the data in database but return a `Model` object. Then you can set the `ip` property of that model object and save that model object. Your code will be something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']  #get the ip address
    m = form.save(false)
    m.ip = ip #set the ip address here
    m.save() # now saved to database
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        form.ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] # added 'ip' to the form object here
        if form.is_valid():                 
            m = form.save()
            return HttpResponse(2)
    else:
        form = MessageForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

The good part of a model form is that is always has an `instance` attribute that holds the actual model instance, even if it doesn't exist yet in the database. Rafiqunnabi's code can be shortened to this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    m = form.save()
```